# Where can I find mysqldump.exe 10.4.22?

Tags: mysql, database, dump

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem ? I've searched this version of mysql on the official website but it does not exist, what can I do ?

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

Comment: Version 10.x is MariaDB, not MySQL. You should get mysqldump from Mariadb.com

Comment: How did you end up with a mismatch version?

Comment: I don't know, I just downloaded mysql and XAMP lol. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://mariadb.org/mariadb/all-releases/ ,
download the version you need ,
copy and paste the mysqldump.exe to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE ,
And go to MySQL workbench -> Edit ->Preferences ->Administration -> set the path to copied mysqldump.exe(C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe)